# How to make instagram chat screen(UI) for left swipe to see time in android

Tags: time, android-recyclerview, instagram, message

How to show time of messages in chat screen on left swipe like Instagram chat screen.I have used recycler view for showing messages but have no idea how to achieve time show on swipe just like instagram does